# Why is tensor networks applicable only to ground states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, variational-principle, ground-state, tensor-network

When one uses tensor network as a wave function ansatz for a variational method, we usually use this scheme to find a ground state. Why can’t we apply the tensor network formalism to find any excited states?

Comment: variational methods are good at finding ground states, and it is more difficult to find excited states. I am not an expert on tensor networks but if the principal idea is variational, I would guess that this is the reason. If you'd like I can explain in an answer why is that so

Comment: I would also like to add that excitations are definitely doable using tensor networks methods, e.g. the "quasiparticle excitation ansatz" (see section 6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07006 and numerous other papers)

Comment: The most common tensor network ansatz used (e.g. MPS and PEPS) describe states with area law entanglement. This is the correct entanglement structure for low lying states in a wide range of cases, but not suitable for higher energy states, which generally show volume law entanglement

Comment: @yu-v Could you explain why is that so?

Comment: @NDewolf Thanks for sharing the article! I haven’t aware of this. I skimmed the section. Is this like magnons in quantum many body system? Is this procedure artificial for true excited particles? not quasiparticles

Comment: @BySymmetry Of course such tensor networks possess area law scaling (wrt the physical system size) of the upper bound for EE. But my point is, if you consider a fairly general class of TN, there should be some TN with volume law entanglement. (e.g. MERA capped with MPDO) TNs are not suitable for excited states in general?

Comment: @Amplituhedron as from the other answers it seems that the case for tensor networks is more complicated, I will not write it an answer. In general, for a variational method we try to find a set of parameters in the wave function such that $E(\lambda) = \langle \psi_{\lambda} | H | \psi_{\lambda} \rangle$ is minimal, as $\langle H \rangle \geq E_{\rm{ground state}}$ for all states. This give us a wave-function for the ground state. To get something above that we can repeat the process after projecting-out the wave function we found, but this is more elaborate and technically cumbersome.

Comment: @Amplituhedron These quasiparticle are indeed the manifestation of spinons and magnons in the tensor network framework.